# Loading game bitmaps: best practice

Tags: android, memory, loading, textures

Suppose we have a game with multiple scenes like menu, level menu etc. What is a better practice to implement when loading the game's bitmaps in memory?

1. Load only the current scene's bitmaps, and then unload them dynamically when changing to another scene (can cause glitches when changing since the unload/load process takes time).
2. Load all bitmaps at the start of the game and unload them all when the game is closed (can cause out of memory errors, since there can be many bitmaps).

What is considered best? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common approach i see is:

All non actual game related graphics get loaded on start(this is menu, level select, high score and options)

And when a level is selected start loading those graphics, unload the ones you won't be needing for the next level.

Unloading when the game is closed is not needed as android will clear the memory anyway if it's not being used.

Comment: You can't really know when the game is closed, the user might just have received a call for instance. Unless you include your own exit button, which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @user999717 That is very true.